how to add metadata to s3 file/object while uploading object programatically?
I have a bucket created via terraform, when file is uploaded to this bucket , can we add metadata to the file/object? if yes, how would i add metatdata to the file/object being uploaded?
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client("s3")

s3.upload_file("local_file.txt", "my-bucket", "test.txt")

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
  bucket = "test-bucket007"
  tags = {
    Name        = "bucket"
    Environment = "test"
  }
}


Like this:
s3.upload_file(
    "local_file.txt",
    "my-bucket",
    "test.txt",
    ExtraArgs={"Metadata": {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2"}},
)


thank you. one follow up question , if you don't mind , does storing metadata , cost more? and I'm assuming , i can query or retrieve objects based on metadata? , can you link me to an example, if this is possible


It doesn't cost more than the storage (IIRC you get ~40kb of metadata storage per obj, so the metadata cost is trivial)  2. Query or retrieve objects based on metadata is not supported.

